# Calling matlab with timeout function from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, matlab, shell, timeout

I have a pipeline of matlab codes, and one of the scripts will hang indefinitely under certain circumstances. Currently, I have a shell script that calls each piece of the pipeline. However, I would like to "timeout" the piece of matlab code that might hang indefinitely.

The below code works flawlessly if it is typed directly into a terminal window. However, when this code is a line in a shell script it will not execute the matlab script.

```
timeout --kill-after=25 25 matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('testing.m'); exit;"
```

When executed from a shell script, nothing happens until the timeout and kill option is reached. Also,

```
matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('testing.m'); exit;"
```

Runs without problems in a shell script.

Comment: Considering using '--foreground': 'timeout --foreground --kill-after =10 25 matlab ...' If the testing.m need to interact with the terminal it might help.

Comment: Also note that the kill-after timeout is usually much smaller that the actual timeout - this provide a safety net, if the TERM signal does not cause the process to get killed.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Also thanks for the advice.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Per comment above, adding the --foreground address the problem.

Most likely, The 'testing.m' need access to TTY/TTY signals. By default, the timeout will run the command as a child process, w

```
timeout --foreground --kill-after=10 25 matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('testing.m'); exit;"
```

From the timeout man page:
`--foreground
     when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt, allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals; in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out`